# how to combine following three values in python/pyserial to get one value

Tags: python, pyserial

I'm trying to combine three values that I got through serial port using pyserial. These values are corresponding to 3 parts of a 24bit data transmitted from and fpga board and I want to get the 24 bit data in python script. What kind of a conversion and combination process can give me back this 24 bit data? I'm reading data using below simple while loop...

```
import serial

port = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200)
file = open("my_file.txt","a")
while True:   

   message = ord(port.read())
   print(message)          
   file.write(str(message) + "\n")

file.close()
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you more specify your question? I don't see in the provided code any spot where are 3 variables which should be combined.

Comment: This script continuously read data from serial port and print/store them. Data stream is something like ... 23, 45, 200 ... These are first second and third part of a 24 bit data "00010111" , "00101101" , "11001000". So I want to merge these three pieces to reproduce a 24bit data as  " 000101110010110111001000" and then convert it to corresponding decimal value which is 1519048 for this example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `struct` module (built-in Python) for pack those 3 bytes into one:

```
import struct

#Your code ...

while True:
  message = port.read(3) #Read 3 bytes at once
  combined = struct.unpack(">I", b'\x00' + message)[0]
```

The `>I` means you decoding 32-bit unsigned integer (`I`) saved in big-endian (`>`). Because `struct.unpack()` doesn't support 24-bit numbers I added 1 zero byte to the start of the 24-bit number which effectively creates 32-bit number.